# \newunicodechar only if undeclared?

Tags: luatex, unicode

I am using `LuaLaTeX`. Some of the source files I receive contain Unicode characters that are not universally supported. So far, so common:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
    \newunicodechar{^^^^2e3a}{—\,—} % hair spaces for testing only
    \newunicodechar{^^^^2e3b}{—\,—\,—}

\begin{document}

This is a TWO-EM DASH (U+2E3A): ⸺

This is a THREE-EM DASH (U+2E3B): ⸻

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note how in the above example I had to “fake” (redefine) two characters, since Latin Modern Unicode misses the required glyphs. But many other fonts do have them: Is there a way for me to use `\newunicodechar` (or some other method) conditionally only for fonts that need it? I'd hate to use some *ersatz* character or method if the glyph were, in fact, present in the chosen font.

**EDIT:** Following David's advice, I have made some progress:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\iffontchar\font "2e3a \else {%
\newunicodechar{^^^^2e3a}{—\,—}%
} \fi

\begin{document}

This font has \iffontchar\font "2014 \else {\textbf{no}} \fi support for EM DASH (U+2014): —

This font has \iffontchar\font "2e3a \else {\textbf{no}} \fi support for TWO-EM DASH (U+2E3A): ⸺

\end{document}
```

It doesn't work in the preamble, though. (Whereas `\newunicodechar` doesn't work outside of it.) What am I doing wrong? No errors, just not the expected result.

[image]

**EDIT2**: I figured it out. See full answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For luatex (or xetex would be the same) you are not using CM fonts but Latin Modern Unicode. For Unicode TeX you can ask if the current font has the character with

```
\iffontchar \font "2E3A
```

Comment: Yes, this is for `LuaLaTex` … I believe I did say as much in the very first line :-) I stand corrected re: the font.

Comment: @Ingmar sorry, adjusted the wording:-)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out `\iffontchar`, it gives me something to work with.

Comment: Got it to work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

You want to test the existence at the point of usage. I left `\,` instead of the probably wanted `\!` just to see the difference.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{⸺}{\iffontchar\font`⸺\relax ⸺\else---\,---\fi}

\newfontface{\test}{Source Sans Pro}

\begin{document}

⸺

\test⸺

\end{document}
```

[image]

The glyph does not exist in Latin Modern, but it does in Source Sans Pro.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. There was a syntax error after all. I am posting my working solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\iffontchar\font "2e3a%
\relax\else\newunicodechar{^^^^2e3a}{—\,—}%
\fi

\begin{document}

This font has \iffontchar\font "2014 
\else {\textbf{no}} \fi support for EM DASH (U+2014): —

This font has \iffontchar\font "2e3a 
\else {\textbf{no}} \fi support for TWO-EM DASH (U+2E3A): ⸺

\end{document}
```

[image]